# array has more elements than it's slice

Tags: python, numpy, sparse-matrix

I am scattering the nonzero elements of a numpy array (a raster plot) however array has more points than it should actually have.

`fig,ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize = (20,21))`

`raster_plot(all_concatenated[subject_names[0]][:,0:10000], ax = ax[0])`
`raster_plot(all_concatenated[subject_names[0]][:,0:8000], ax = ax[1])`

where

```
def raster_plot(spikes, ax, t = 500): 

    binned_spikes = bin_time_series(spikes, binsize = t, total_frame = spikes.shape[1])
    n,t,l = binned_spikes.shape
    
    #cmap = plt.cm.Spectral
    #norm = plt.Normalize(vmin = 0, vmax = float(np.max(spikes)))
    
    for i in range(n):
        for k in range(l):
            for j in range(t):
                if binned_spikes[i][j][k] == 0: pass
                else:
                    ax.scatter(k*t+j, i, s = 5, c = 'b', marker = 'x')#, norm = norm, cmap = cmap)
                    ax.set_title('Spike Raster Plot', fontsize = 20)
                    ax.set_xlabel('Time (Frames)', fontsize = 15)
                    ax.set_ylabel('Neuron ID', fontsize = 15)
                    ax.set_xticks([t*i for i in range(l+1)])
                    ax.set_yticks([5*i for i in range(int(n/5)+1)]+[n])
                    ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', labelsize = 10)
                    ax.tick_params(axis = 'y', labelsize = 13)
```

and

```
def bin_time_series(array, binsize, total_frame):

    binned_spikes = []

    for i in range(len(array)):
        A = array[i].reshape(binsize, int(total_frame/binsize))
        binned_spikes.append(A)
    
    return(np.array(binned_spikes, dtype=np.int32))
```

when I look at the first 8000 time points neurons with id 94-113 has no spikes which is what the array actually is however when I look at the first 10000 time points, I'm seeing extra spikes that should not exist. One strange thing is those spikes that should not exist in the 10000 slice are all near the multiples of 500.

Is this a sparsity issue? Am I going crazy or what am I missing?

[image: raster plots]

Comment: `...what am I missing?` - I'm confident that Matplotlib is doing exactly what you asked it to do. There isn't enough information in your question. Please read [mre], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: You haven't shown what `raster_plot` is - maybe artifacts from that processing? Maybe something to do with the chained indexing - `all_concatenated[subject_names[0]][:,0:10000]`?

Comment: thanks for the heads up, just edited the question and added the function raster plot.

Comment: I'm using the same chain indexing for the 8000 slice too though :/